# What is the dimens res folder for a Nexus 10?

Tags: android, android-resolution

I'm trying to use values from my dimens file to target the Nexus 10. I have the folder set up as values-sw720dp-xhdpi but this doesnt work. I have also tried values-sw720dp-xxhdpi but still this doesnt work.

What is the correct implementation of the folder where I can store my dimens values for a Nexus 10?

I am testing this on an emulator which runs perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think:

```
values-sw720dp-land
```

is what you're going for.

Comment: Thanks I was able to get it with values-sw800dp-hdpi

Comment: values-sw720dp should be all you need. This only works for a 720dp smallest width device when it's in landscape configuration.